# Does EC2 support AES-NI instructions? If so, is there a particular instance type?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-web-services, openssl

Trying to determine if EC2 supports and makes available this newer instruction set.

Comment: Just fire up a t1.micro instance and test it for yourself. It would cost all of a few cents.

Answer (score 6):

When this answer was first written, many instance types did, but not all.
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ currently (2015-Dec-10) says "Intel AES New Instructions (AES-NI): Intel AES-NI encryption instruction set improves upon the original Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) algorithm to provide faster data protection and greater security. All current generation EC2 instances support this processor feature."

Answer (score 4):

from my testing, no.  all of the ec2 instances I've tested use intel E5xxx or X5xxx cores, which don't support AES_NI.   You'll need E7s for that.   maybe we'll get lucky when new hardware trickles in.....

Answer (score 0):

According to https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#Instance_Features, all modern instant types based on an Intel processor support AES-NI